# Regex expression:)

Tags: regex

Email Masking..

```
Sample input :- Testuser@gmail.com
Sample output :- T******r@g***.com
```

First letter of username, 6 asterisks, last letter of username, @ character, first letter of domain, 3 asterisks,then extension.

what is the regex expression for this?

I need the code like the way below,

```
String Email= Email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?@)", "*");
```

Comment: You don't need regex for this. It can be done easily in any language/script.

Comment: This is not a regex related question. Do state in what language or script you are planning to do this. Edit the question and select the specific language in Tag

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible Javascript solution

```
var email = "Testuser@gmail.com"
var re1 = /(?<=[A-Za-z0-9]).+(?=[A-Za-z0-9]\@)/ // Replaces username with "******"
var re2 = /(?<=\@[A-Za-z0-9]).+(?=\.com)/ // Replaces domain with "***"
var modemail = email.replace(re1, "******").replace(re2, "***")
```

Comment: Can we get a single regex pattern instead of using 2 regex